# Python remove JSON substring

Tags: python, string, json

If I have a string where there is a valid JSON substring like this one:

```
 mystr = '100{"1":2, "3":4}312'
```

What is the best way to do extract just the JSON string?  The numbers outside can be anything (except a `{` or `}`), including newlines and things like that.

Just to be clear, this is the result I want

```
  newStr = '{"1":2, "3":4}'
```

The best way I can think of do this is to use `find` and `rfind` and then take the substring.  This seems too verbose to me and it isn't python 3.0 compliant (which I would prefer but is not essential)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What isn't Python 3-compliant about `find` and `rfind`?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions

Comment: why not to use regular expression (with MULTILINE flag)?

Comment: @devin: That does not mean what you think it means. The functions were removed from the `string` module because they were redundant. The built-in `str` class includes `find` and `rfind`, and they are **not** deprecated. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the following code very much assumes that there is nothing other than non-bracket material on either side of the JSON string.

```
import re
matcher = re.compile(r"""
^[^\{]*          # Starting from the beginning of the string, match anything that isn't an opening bracket
       (         # Open a group to record what's next
        \{.+\}   # The JSON substring
       )         # close the group
 [^}]*$          # at the end of the string, anything that isn't a closing bracket
""", re.VERBOSE)

# Your example
print matcher.match('100{"1":2, "3":4}312').group(1)

# Example with embedded hashmap
print matcher.match('100{"1":{"a":"b", "c":"d"}, "3":4}312').group(1)
```

The short, non-precompiled, non-commented version:

```
import re
print re.match("^[^\{]*(\{[^\}]+\})[^}]*$", '100{"1":2, "3":4}312').group(1)
```

Although for the sake of maintenance, commenting regular expressions is very much preferred.